# Fresh Red Hat Enterprise Linux fails to install httpd using yum

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, installation, redhat, yum

I'm trying to install a LAMP stack in a fresh red hat server but yum is misbehaving. Being linux illiterate I'm at a loss.

```
$yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Nothing to do
```

My yum config

```
$ cat /etc/yum.conf
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1 

# Note: yum-RHN-plugin doesn't honor this.
metadata_expire=1h

# Default.
# installonly_limit = 3

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Other stuff in the yum.repos.d dir

```
$ ls -lah /etc/yum.repos.d/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Feb  4 01:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 59 root root 4.0K Feb  4 01:28 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  561 Mar 10  2010 rhel-debuginfo.repo
```

What could be going on? I thought "out of the box" RHEL5.5 would be friendlier :)

Comment: You could try `yum provides httpd` to try to track down the right package, but you might also want try `which httpd` (or `whereis httpd` or something similar) because the binary may actually be installed already. Also voting to move this to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), it seems a better fit there.

Comment: @eldarerathis, here's the output of your commands:
`yum provides httpd`
Loaded plugins: security
Warning: 3.0.x versions of yum would erroneously match against filenames.
 You can use "*/httpd" and/or "*bin/httpd" to get that behaviour
No Matches found
`which httpd`
/usr/bin/which: no httpd in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
`whereis httpd`
httpd:

Comment: Hey, you might be missing some RPM's. I'm not sure which RPM exactly, but I ran into an issue like this over a year ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Since this server was automatically created using an image from the cloud it never got registered with the red hat network. After doing that, yum started behaving again.

Comment: Yeh, I was going to suggest that this might be the case due to the "No package httpd available." line. "yum repolist" will generally let you know what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the RPM is located in your CD or ISO?

RHEL Server 5.5 has a file /Server/httpd-2.2.3-43.el5.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I don't really have an ISO since this is a Cloud Server. I'll dig around for that RPM and if I can find it I'll try to install from that.